# how can i get the input from the entry widget, tkinter, python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I searched how to get the input and this should work but it doesnt...
i dont understand why it doesnt working... its start running and get stuck in the mainloop line... it shows nothing

```
from Tkinter import *


class GUI:

def __init__(self):

    self.root = Tk()

    self.label1 = Label(self.root, text="name")
    self.label2 = Label(self.root, text="password")
    self.entry1 = Entry(self.root)
    self.entry2 = Entry(self.root, show="*")
    self.button = Button(self.root, text="hello", command=self.printName)
    self.button.pack()

    self.label1.grid(row=0, sticky=W)  # N, S, E, W
    self.label2.grid(row=1, sticky=E)
    self.entry1.grid(row=0, column=1)
    self.entry2.grid(row=1, column=1)

    self.c = Checkbutton(self.root, text="forgot my password")
    self.c.grid(columnspan=2)

    self.root.mainloop()

def printName(self):

    print self.entry1.get()


hi = GUI()
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using both `grid` and `pack` for widgets that share the same parent. You can't do that -- you have to pick one or the other.

Also, to be pedantic you should ove the call of `self.root.mainloop()` outside of the `__init__`. The reason is that with it being inside, the object is never fully created because `mainloop` won't return until the widget is destroyed. Typically you call `mainloop` in the same scope that created the root window.

For example:

```
hi = GUI()
hi.root.mainloop()
```

If you don't like referencing the internal widget, give `GUI` a method like `start` or `mainloop`:

```
class GUI():
    ...
    def start(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

...
hi = GUI()
hi.start()
```